# Non-destructive explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Exploding a string is destructive in that the string you explode against is destroyed.

```
$str = "ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJK";
$arr = explode("DE",$str);
```

$arr is now:

```
[0] = ABC
[1] = FGHIJKABC
[2] = FGHIJK
```

Is there a similar (and efficient) method for exploding the same string by "DE" but winding up with:

```
[0] = ABC
[1] = DEFGHIJKABC
[2] = DEFGHIJK
```

The only other argument for `explode` is a limit on how many pieces are returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) and [lookahead assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

```
$arr = preg_split('[(?=DE)]', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and documentation reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJK";
$arr = preg_split('[(?=DE)]', $str);
echo $arr[0]."<br/>";
echo $arr[1]."<br/>";
echo $arr[2];
?>
```

Comment: SO doesn't show this, but this answer was posted about 15 minutes after the accepted answer.  Identical, but the other came first.